find matches and replace with dynamic values
I need to find and replace some characters with other characters (or just delete them).
Replacement rules: if the first character found is "A", then replace this character with the value of currNumber +100; if the first character found is "B", then replace this character with the value of currNumber -10. And if the characters "*_" are found (the _ sign can be repeated as many times as you like), then simply replace with "".
Unfortunately my version of the code does not work. Perhaps the search does not start from the beginning every time
    Dim xStr_1 As Long    ' A
    Dim xStr_2 As Long    ' B
    Dim xStr_3 As Long    ' *_
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim  currNumber As long
    
    currNumber = 0
    
    xStr_1 = InStr(1, Selection, "A")
    xStr_2 = InStr(1, Selection, "B")
    xStr_3 = InStr(1, Selection, "*_")
    
    if xStr_1 > 0 and xStr_1 < xStr_2 and xStr_1 < xStr_3 then i = xStr_1
    if xStr_2 > 0 and xStr_2 < xStr_1 and xStr_2 < xStr_3 then i = xStr_2
    if xStr_3 > 0 and xStr_3 < xStr_1 and xStr_3 < xStr_2 then i = xStr_3
    
    Do While i <> 0
    
        If xStr_1 = i Then
            
            With Selection.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "A"
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                With .Replacement
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Text = currNumber + 100
                End With
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
            End With
            
            currNumber  = currNumber + 100
            
        elseif xStr_2 = i Then
            
            With Selection.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "B"
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                With .Replacement
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Text = currNumber - 10
                End With
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
            End With
                
            currNumber  = currNumber - 10
    
        elseif xStr_3 = i Then
            
            With Selection.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "\*{1}\_{1,}"
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                With .Replacement
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Text = currNumber
                End With
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
            End With
                
        end if

        xStr_1 = InStr(1, Selection, "A")
        xStr_2 = InStr(1, Selection, "B")
        xStr_3 = InStr(1, Selection, "*_")
        
        if xStr_1 > 0 and xStr_1 < xStr_2 and xStr_1 < xStr_3 then i = xStr_1
        if xStr_2 > 0 and xStr_2 < xStr_1 and xStr_2 < xStr_3 then i = xStr_2
        if xStr_3 > 0 and xStr_3 < xStr_1 and xStr_3 < xStr_2 then i = xStr_3   
    
    Loop    


And if the characters "*_" are found (the _ sign can be repeated as many times as you like), then simply replace with "", but .Text = currNumber replaces *_ with currNumber in your script. Which one is correct?

Try something like:
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
i = CLng(InputBox("Starting number?", , 0))
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Text = "*_"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "<[AB]>"
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    Select Case .Text
      Case "A"
        i = i + 100
        .Text = i
      Case "B"
        i = i - 10
        .Text = i
    End Select
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


The following If clauses don't work as expected. For example, the selection in Word is shown in the first snapshot. In this case, xStr_1 = 16, and both xStr_2 and xStr_3 = 0. However, despite xStr_1 > 0, the conditions xStr_1 < xStr_2 and xStr_1 < xStr_3 are evaluated as False. The value of i is 0 after three If clauses.
    if xStr_1 > 0 and xStr_1 < xStr_2 and xStr_1 < xStr_3 then i = xStr_1
    if xStr_2 > 0 and xStr_2 < xStr_1 and xStr_2 < xStr_3 then i = xStr_2
    if xStr_3 > 0 and xStr_3 < xStr_1 and xStr_3 < xStr_2 then i = xStr_3

Pls try.
Sub demo()
    Dim xStr_1 As Long    ' A
    Dim xStr_2 As Long    ' B
    Dim xStr_3 As Long    ' *_
    Dim i As Long
    Dim currNumber As Long
    currNumber = 0
    xStr_1 = InStr(1, Selection, "A")
    xStr_2 = InStr(1, Selection, "B")
    xStr_3 = InStr(1, Selection, "*_")
    If xStr_1 > 0 And (xStr_1 < xStr_2 Or xStr_2 = 0) And (xStr_1 < xStr_3 Or xStr_3 = 0) Then i = xStr_1
    If xStr_2 > 0 And (xStr_2 < xStr_1 Or xStr_1 = 0) And (xStr_2 < xStr_3 Or xStr_3 = 0) Then i = xStr_2
    If xStr_3 > 0 And (xStr_3 < xStr_1 Or xStr_1 = 0) And (xStr_3 < xStr_2 Or xStr_2 = 0) Then i = xStr_3
    Debug.Print xStr_1, xStr_2, xStr_3
    Debug.Print i
End Sub



Refactor it as a UDF.

Sub demo()
    Dim xStr_1 As Long    ' A
    Dim xStr_2 As Long    ' B
    Dim xStr_3 As Long    ' *_
    Dim i As Long
    Dim currNumber As Long
    currNumber = 0
    xStr_1 = InStr(1, Selection, "A")
    xStr_2 = InStr(1, Selection, "B")
    xStr_3 = InStr(1, Selection, "*_")
    i = Get1stMatch(xStr_1, xStr_2, xStr_3)
    Debug.Print xStr_1, xStr_2, xStr_3
    Debug.Print i
End Sub

Function Get1stMatch(x1 As Long, x2 As Long, x3 As Long) As Long
    Get1stMatch = 0
    If x1 > 0 And (x1 < x2 Or x2 = 0) And (x1 < x3 Or x3 = 0) Then
        Get1stMatch = x1
        Exit Function
    End If
    If x2 > 0 And (x2 < x1 Or x1 = 0) And (x2 < x3 Or x3 = 0) Then
        Get1stMatch = x2
        Exit Function
    End If
    If x3 > 0 And (x3 < x1 Or x1 = 0) And (x3 < x2 Or x2 = 0) Then
        Get1stMatch = x3
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function

